# how to update a number in html using js

Tags: javascript, html, numbers

I want to add 1 to a number every .5 seconds and display it on a website. This is the code.

```
<p id="score">
       0
    </p>
<script></script>
```

I want to change what is written inside the `<p>` tag

Comment: "Give me a script that does X so I can copy/paste it" is not really a question for SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to access the `p` element through the [Document Object Model API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) and update the contents of the element within a function that is set to run at .5 second intervals using a [timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```js
// Get a reference to the paragraph element
const p = document.getElementById("score");

// Set up a recurring timer that takes a function as
// a callback and runs every .5 seconds (500 milliseconds)
// Since the p holds text, putting a + before its contents
// implcitly converts it to a number
setInterval(function(){
  p.textContent = +p.textContent + 1;
}, 500);
```

```html
<p id="score">0</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(function(){ 
var score = parseInt(document.getElementById("score").innerText);
document.getElementById("score").innerText = score + 1;
}, 500);
```

```html
<p id="score">
       0
    </p>
```

Comment: In question, it's every .5 seconds

Comment: Btw please add some text explanation to your question to accompany the example, it will enhance its value

Comment: Thanks, I will take care of this next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  var score = 0;
  var scoreElement = document.getElementById('score');
  window.setInterval(function(){
    //this function is called every .5 seconds
    score ++;
    //set text
    scoreElement.innerHtml = score;
  }, 500)
</script>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <button class="btn">Click me</button>
    <p class="score">0</p>
    
    <script>
      
     let score = 0;

    document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', function () {
    score++;
    document.querySelector('.score').textContent = score;
   });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

First, we need to get the p tag in the JS

We can do this in two ways,

1. `const p = document.getElementById('score');`
   or
2. `const p = document.querySelector('#score');`

In the second method, we use `#` since it is an ID. If it were a class, we would use `.`

Then, to keep track of the score, we need to define a variable, so

`score = 0;`

Now, we need to make the code run after every .5 seconds, so we need to use the `setInterval();` function

so

```
function() {

our code here

},

our interval here

);
```

So inside the function, we need to increase the score

so `score = score + 1`

Now, we need to modify the text, so we will use the `innerText` method on `p`, so

`p.innerText = score`

Now our `setInterval()` should look like this

```
setInterval(function() {
score = score + 1;
p.innerText = score;
}
);
```

Now, we need to define the interval, so after the function ends, we will add `500`. This will add the interval of 500ms or .5 seconds.

In the end, our code would be something like this:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('#score');

score = 0;

setInterval(function() {
score = score + 1;
p.innerText = score;
}, 
500
);
```

```html
<p id="score"></p>
```

Full code is here on this Github Gist

https://gist.github.com/AaravHattangadi/ebba0b0c3d088eb471824111db51b594